# Unable to find @JsonProperty annotation with field.getAnnotation

Tags: java, kotlin, reflection

I'm using kotlin 1.4.31.
My class is like below

```kotlin
class SomeClass(
  @JsonProperty("trans_name")
  val transactionName,
  @JsonProperty("trans_dtime")
  val transactionDateTime
  // ...
)
```

I used reflection to get `@JsonProperty`'s value because it's needed in our code.

```kotlin
SomeClass::class.java.declaredFields
  .map { it.declaredAnnotationByType(JsonProperty::class.java) }
  .map { it.first().value }
```

But exception was occurred

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Array is empty
```

Exception reason is reflection couldn't find `@JsonProperty` annotation.
Even when I called `it.declaredAnnotations()` directly, the size was zero.

Oddly enough, annotations like `@Column` work well.

What is different between `@Column` and `@JsonProperty`,
and how can I access `@JsonProperty` using reflection?

Comment: You’re using Kotlin - annotations have targets. An annotation on a property is not the same as an annotation on a Java field. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets

Comment: @BoristheSpider I didn't know cause I'm beginner of kotlin . Thanks!